# Thread Safe MakeObjectInstance?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

How can I use `MakeObjectInstance` in a thread? I know there are thread safe `AllocateHwnd` functions posted on various places but I can't seem to find a thread safe function of `MakeObjectInstance`.

I found this http://www.atozed.com/Intraweb/Blog/20121030.EN.aspx however its not for XE6?

Comment: You can code one yourself. What is the use case?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Don't kno how to code one myself. Thats why I asked the question.

Comment: Use the same coding as in the RTL. But simplify it somewhat. You just need to allocate some executable memory. Complication in RTL is to avoid allocating too many pages. Best of all is to avoid the need in the first place. Won't you tell us what the problem is?

Comment: What's wrong with AllocateHWnd, threadsafe version

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can't be used with `CreateWindowEx`. Thus patching `MakeObjectInstance` function is better instead.

Comment: Why do you need a `TWinContol` in a thread at all? Again, what is the use case?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I found a thread safe function but its not for XE6. Made by Atozed..

Comment: As both Remy and David have asked (and which you've ignored both times), *why do you need a `TWinControl` in a thread*? The VCL is not thread-safe, and `TWinControl` is part of the VCL, so `TWinControl` is not thread-safe.

Comment: What is wrong with the [code supplied by Primoz](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2007/06/allocatehwnd-is-not-thread-safe.html)?

Comment: @KenWhite Have you read what I've actually asked?

Comment: Yes, I've read what you asked. My comment was addressing the comment you made (and have since deleted) that [Remy also commented about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956840/thread-safe-makeobjectinstance?noredirect=1#comment36908501_23956840), where you said "I need access to a TWinControl from a thread". Ignoring requests for more information isn't really conducive to getting people here to help you, I'm afraid. Neither is removing comments to which people responded and then trying to treat them as being foolish for what they asked/said.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, from the comments, that you wish to create a window handle outside the main thread. You correctly note that you cannot use `AllocateHWnd` because it is not thread safe. However, you can use a thread safe version, for instance the one provided by Primoz.

You comment that it does not allow you to use `CreateWindowEx`. But since the code is supplied as source it is trivial to customise it to fit your needs.

This is a much cleaner solution to the problem than `MakeObjectInstance`. It avoids creating a runtime thunk and makes use of the instance memory of a window handle. The very reason that memory exists.

Comment: I've updated the question. Making your answer obsolete.

Comment: I don think there is any obsolescence